# how to get attribute from server in jsp via javascript?

Tags: javascript, spring

```
@RequestMapping("/toTicketRuleSetting/{ticketTypeId}")
public String goToAssistSecretary(@PathVariable("ticketTypeId") long ticketTypeId, ModelMap model) {
    model.put("ticketTypeId", ticketTypeId);
    model.put("tabId", 0); 
    return "backend/basic/ticketRuleSetting";
}
```

in the spring mvc , tabId in model will return jsp page,
i want to get the tabId in my jsp page via javascript, how can i do ?
here is javascript code in my jsp page:

```
  window.onload = function (){ 
   <c:set var="tabId" value="${tabId}"/> 
   <c:if test = "{tabId.value==5}"> 
         $("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active", 5 );
   </c:if >
```

};

please help me !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Model in method parameter, here is the code :

```
@RequestMapping("/toTicketRuleSetting/{ticketTypeId}")
public String goToAssistSecretary(@PathVariable("ticketTypeId") long ticketTypeId, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("ticketTypeId", ticketTypeId);
    model.addAttribute("tabId", 0); 
    return "backend/basic/ticketRuleSetting";
}
```

Then, call it in your function like you did. CCMIIW :)